# Flutter: PhoneAccount connection service requires BIND_TELECOM_CONNECTION_SERVICE permission

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages, flutter-android

I'm using flutter_callKeep , but I'm getting the above error.

These are permissions in my manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_TELECOM_CONNECTION_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />


 <application>....
        
        <service android:name="myAPPID.VoiceConnectionService"
        android:label="MY APP NAME"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_TELECOM_CONNECTION_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.telecom.ConnectionService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Comment: I am having the same issue have you fixed it?

Comment: Hello , CallKeep sdk flutter , ask phone account permission --> open call account setting screen in Mi phone work fine. but in oppo or some other devices does not open call account screen,so how we provide phone account permission?

Answer (score 1):

It is because of android:name in the service.
try replacing `android:name="myAPPID.VoiceConnectionService"` with `android:name="io.wazo.callkeep.VoiceConnectionService"`

Comment: Hello ,
 CallKeep sdk flutter , ask phone account permission --> open  call account  setting  screen in Mi phone work fine. but in oppo or some other devices does not open call account screen,so  how we provide phone account permission?

Comment: However, even making this change will not make any difference to some phones (OPPO, OnePlus - likely others as well) as they do not have a page in the device settings for Call Account.